# re-enable disabled eslint rule within file via eslint-enable

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

Can we somehow re-enable lint rule within specific file, if it has been turned off within `.eslintrc.js` config

Let's say I have (.eslintrc.js):

```js
module.exports = {
  // omiting extends and plugin etc...
  rules: {
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So `eslint-enable` looked like the proper solution, unfortunately that doesn't work.

```js
// ❌DOESN'T WORK
/* eslint-enable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */

export const useCount = () => {
  const [value,setValue] = useState()

  const inc = useCallback(()=>{
    setValue(value+1)
  // EXPECT ESLINT WARNING
  },[])

  return {inc, value}
}
```

Dunno if it's a bug or "works as expected" behaviour though....